# Accessing Multiple Arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters

I'm trying to create a function for two or more parameters. However I don't understand why for sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);

```
function sym(args) {
  return args;
}
```

only return [1, 2, 3]

but

```
 function sym(args) {
  return args;
 }
```

returns { 0: [ 1, 2, 3 ], 1: [ 5, 2, 1, 4 ] }.

and

```
function sym(args) {
 args = arguments;
 console.log(args);
}
```

returns { 0: [Circular], 1: [ 5, 2, 1, 4 ] }

Comment: Both `sym` functions are the same?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a difference between those functions?

Comment: How about `...args` ?

Comment: Replace `args` with `...args`. Otherwise, use `arguments` instead (but you will need to elborate that instead). the input in the first two examples seems different, anyway.

Comment: I don't think the input is the same for the examples you're giving, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining a function with a single argument called `args`. What you are looking for is called *variadic arguments* (or variadic parameters) which means "0 or more arguments".

Either use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
function sym(...args) {
  return args;
}
```

Or if you're using an old version of JavaScript use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```
function sym() {
  return Array.from(arguments);
}
```

Your last example is quite beautiful actually. When you do `args = arguments` (except in strict mode) you are *modifying `arguments` implicitly* and giving it a reference to itself (hence the `[circular]`). I warmly recommend [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to avoid these quirks.

Comment: ...that means `arguments` holds References to the parameters and resolves them on lookup 0_0 ?

Comment: @JonasWilms yes :) Only in "loose mode", in strict mode there is no circular modification. It's one of the silliest gotchas in JavaScript. Strict mode is really about scoping and enabling things like SES (secure ECMAScript) rather than catching developer errors - just don't tell the developers :D

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to write & destructure, IE:

```js
sym([[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5]]);

function sym([arg1, arg2]) {
 console.log(arg1,arg2);
}

or

function sym(args) {
 console.log(args);
}
```